# Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list" how to solve this problem?

Tags: performance, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list" how to solve this problem?

i'm trying to run the Camera but nothing happen and the log says 'access denied finding property 'persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list' and
access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"

what should i do? anyone?

Comment: have you find any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

It took my time up to 2 days and I suffer on Android device like Xiaomi or Oppo. Finally solution of me  simply restarting the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and allow camera permission for that app...

It solved my problem try it and give me feedback

Comment: Not a answer but a comment.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it on Mi 9T with the issue below.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54619#issuecomment-753758435

Content of the link:

> Latest (UNPUBLISHED) camera plugin seems resolve the issue. Tested on OnePlus 6T with Android 10, 0.6.3+2 is still broken. Use the plugin in your pubspec.yaml like this and give it a shot.

```yaml
camera:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/flutter/plugins.git
    path: packages/camera/camera
    ref: cfa709835ab85702ee8a9ed24bbe7a3fe736c3f5
```