# Android build of OpenCV+Unity asset -> Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera

I´m trying to run a OpenCV+Unity game for Android.
The game works fine on unity but when i build it for android it says

`Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"`

and it crashes.

Im trying with the demo that the assets has and it reports the same problem, so it must be some incompatibility that i don´t recall (it says that the asset is compatible with android builds)
Im only using OpenCV+Unity asset and for libraries OpenCvSharp, Unity and UnityEngine.
Im using a Xiaomi device with MIUI 12
How can i solve this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65149270/access-denied-finding-property-persist-vendor-camera-privapp-list-how-to-solve

Comment: please review [mre]. this problem does not appear to require OpenCV to be reproducible.

Comment: That solution is for Android Studio, but my app is being developed in Unity, and i dont know (if it is possible) how could i change the plugin used by the camera.

Comment: the target is android. android requires apps to ask permission, and to declare that in a manifest file. the core issue is the same.

Comment: I have declared the permissions for camera, frontal camera, and storage, so that is not where the problem is